# How to seperate Username from email while creating an account

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identity

I have a few ideas on how to the default Register Action from the default asp.net core AccountController. It would be a lot better, safer and more secure if it were seperate. But I'm also curious on various ways to handle this.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { 
                UserName = model.Email,   // CHANGE THIS
                Email = model.Email 
            };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Also, how can I query the username input in realtime, so I can make sure it's unique to each user.

Comment: You could do a little bit of research on google. It has lots of tutorials about the realtime checking. 
Now for the username you can change the RegisterViewModel to contain the Username given by your user. Or of course you can make a convention based on the e-mail.

Comment: It's no more safer or more secure to have a separate username and email versus using email for both. The only reason to have a separate username is if that username needs to be used for other purposes where an email would not be appropriate (as a route component, as a display name, etc.). For most scenarios, it's best to use the email as the username.